# What's the difference between these two ways of writting a prototype function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

```
Myfunction.prototype.updateMyFunction = function() {

 //do something

};

Myfunction.prototype = {

 updateMyfunction: function() {

  //do something

 }

};
```

They both produce identical results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is adding a property to `Myfunction.prototype`, while the second one completely replacing the `Myfunction.prototype` with a new object.

The result will not be always identical. Consider this case -

```
Myfunction.prototype.oldMethod = function () {

};

Myfunction.prototype.updateMyFunction = function() {

    //do something

};
```

After adding the last method, you will be able to access both `oldMethod` and `updateMyFunction` later. If you do this -

```
Myfunction.prototype.oldMethod = function () {

};

Myfunction.prototype = {

    updateMyfunction: function() {

        //do something

    }
};
```

then the `oldMethod` will be removed from the prototype chain (since the `prototype` itself is being replaced with a new object) and you will not be able to access it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses the already-existing prototype of MyFunction, while the second one replaces the prototype with a new object.

Some surprising problem with replacing the prototype:

```
var MyFunction = function(){
};

var obj = new MyFunction();

MyFunction.prototype = {    
 updateMyfunction: function() {}
};


var obj2 = new MyFunction();


console.log(obj2 instanceof MyFunction) // true as expected
console.log(obj instanceof MyFunction) // false because the prototype changed
```